I forgot to add a script file to my child theme and it's not showing on Wordpress Theme File Editor
I'm working on an exercise and I forgot to add a script.js file to my child theme. I went and added it by going to the /wp-content/themes/child-theme-folder, but then when I go to the child theme file editor in Wordpress I don't see the script.js file.
I'm a beginner in this so I'd love some help on how I can add this file.

Have you tried switching to a default theme and then switching back to your child theme? If you put a script.js file in your child theme folder, it should display. How are you getting to the Them File Editor? Appearance > Theme File Editor?

You can install the File Manager plugin and view the WordPress files or in your hosting go to File Manager, there you will find all the folders. It's very likely that the.js file is in another folder or you didn't actually create it, it should be visible.
